# Why does the SEC occasionally omit ticker information for a company?

Tags: accounting, sec, edgar

My question is fairly simple: Why does the SEC occasionally omit ticker information for a company?

For example, a well behaved company like Darden Restaurants (DRI) looks [like this](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=940944&accession_number=0000940944-19-000025&xbrl_type=v). The ticker is searchable on EDGAR and is present in the Document and Entity Information of the company's 10K.

On the other hand, a badly behaved company like MVB Financial Corp (MVBF) looks [like this](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=1277902&accession_number=0001277902-19-000008&xbrl_type=v). The ticker is not searchable on EDGAR and is not present in the Document and Entity Information of the company's 10K. It can however be found [here](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1277902/000127790218000064/0001277902-18-000064-index.htm) where you see "MVBF" at the start of the URLs.

Does anyone know why the SEC do this? Could it simply be bad reporting practice from these companies?